# PGSQL error for If statement in function

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function for pgsql where I need to return a boolean if an equipment exists in a lecture hall. I'm getting the following error:

`"ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return boolean"`
    `"DETAIL: Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING."`

```
CREATE FUNCTION hasProjector(int) RETURNS boolean AS $$
        DO
        $do$
        BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM LectureRoomEquipment WHERE LectureRoomID = $1 AND             EquipmentID = 1) THEN
            SELECT true AS hasProjector;
        ELSE
            SELECT false AS hasProjector;
        END IF;
        END
        $do$
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Does anyone advise me what i'm doing wrong and how I can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need plpgsql. Do it as plain SQL

```
create function hasprojector(int) returns boolean as $$

    select exists (
        select *
        from lectureroomequipment
        where lectureroomid = $1 and equipmentid = 1
    );

$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Fair enough, I have deleted my answer. The DO is definitely not required, though.